# Subevents in iCalendar

Tags: icalendar, rfc2445, rfc5545

I ask myself if there is a possible way to create subevents in the [iCalendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) file format.
For example, if an event has duration of 12:00 to 14:00
I would like to divide it into 12:00 to 13:00 and 13:00 to 14:00 as subevents.

NOTE: Apple's iCal uses the kind of subevent I would like to use with "travel time". It adds a kinda subevent before the actual event.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [the iCalendar list of components](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-8.3.1) there is only events listed and no subevents, similarly an event can only have a certain number of properties and none are subevent. One provision in iCaleandar specification is for [relations](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-8.3.8) between components which you could use to define one `VEVENT` as a `CHILD` of another but is not what you are asking for.

If you open the actual event created with travel time by icalendar, you will see that only one `VEVENT` is created and that Apple created a new non-standard property: `X-APPLE-TRAVEL-DURATION` and that the event `DTSTART` is actually set to your event start `DATE-TIME` minus your travel time.

So bottom line to answer your question, it is not possible to create sub-events but multiple ways exist to achieve a similar result as the iCalendar feature you mentionned: create multiple `VEVENT` (one for travel and one for the actual event), create one event of the total duration (event+travel) with only standard properties, create one `VEVENT` with the Apple non-standard property (`X-APPLE-TRAVEL-DURATION`)